# Spark SQL Dataset[Row] collect to driver throw java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql

while using Spark to read a data set by the following code:

```
val df: Dataset[Row] = spark.read.format("csv).schema(schema).load("hdfs://master:9000/mydata")
```

Then I want to collect the data to the driver:

```
val rows_array: Array[Row] = df.collect()
```

An error occurred:

```
java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStream$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:733)
```

The reason for this error seems to be that there are too many data items, because when I use

```
val rows_array: Array[Row] = df.take(10,000,000)
```

it can run successfully. 
But when I use

```
val rows_array: Array[Row] = df.take(100,000,000)
```

the error appeared again(Successfully run the next day, but there are still errors when fetching all data)

Environment:
  Spark 2.4.3
  Hadoop 2.7.7
  Total rows of data about 800,000,000, 12GB
and the memory is enough.

---------------------------------------------------------edit line--------------------------------------------------------

Today I ran it again using the code below:

```
val fields = Array.range(0, 2).map(i => StructField(s"col$i", IntegerType))
val schema: StructType = new StructType(fields)
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate
val df: Dataset[Row] = spark.read.format("csv).schema(schema).load("hdfs://master:9000/mydata")

df.cache()
df.count()

val df_rows: Array[Row] = df.collect()
print("df_rows[0] + df_rows(0))
print("df_rows size:" + df_rows.length)
```

I submit the application by:

```
{SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit --master spark://master:7077 \
    --conf spark.executor.cores=35 \
    --total-executor-cores 105 \
    --executor-memory 145g \
    --driver-memory 200g \
    --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Xms145g" \
    --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Xms200g"
```

The size of the csv file I read is about 12GB, each line in the csv file is two integers, and the memory occupied by df.cache() is 5.5GB.

Environment:
  Spark 2.4.3
  Hadoop 2.7.7
  Total rows of data about 800,000,000, 12GB
  There are three machines in the cluster and they are all workers, the memory of the node submitting the job is 370GB(driver node)

I monitored the spark web ui, and all the tasks were successfully completed(Running time is about 60s), but after more than ten minutes, an error will be generated in the shell(Attention: The process did not exit, and the file in HDFS is ok):

```
WARN hdfs.dfsClient: DFSOutputStream ResponseProcessor exception for block xxxxx
java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:244)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStream$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:733)
WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Error Recovery for block xxxxx in pipeline DatanodeInfoWithStorage[ipxxx,DISK],DatanodeInfoWithStorage[ipxxx,DISK],DatanodeInfoWithStorage[ipxxx,DISK]
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTImeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.BUfferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputSream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStream.run(DFSOutputStream.java:508)
```

And the following two lines of code did not run, because I don't see the output:

```
print("df_rows[0] + df_rows(0))
print("df_rows size:" + df_rows.length)
```

In addition, I also monitored the memory usage of the machine where the driver is located and found that the memory usage has been increasing(After running for 30 minutes, the spark submit process[driver] takes about 120GB)

2020.04.16:

Another information:

Converted to rdd can run successfully:

```
val rows_array: Array[Row] = df.rdd.collect()
```

But in this case, the memory consumption is very expensive(The memory I allocated is almost used up).

Does anyone know the reason? Another question is, why is there such a large memory usage?

Comment: Do you have enough memory configured and available for the driver program?

Comment: Can you add more logs? (e.g driver/failed executors), what is the size of the csv files and how much memory you give to your driver? do you use external configuration or the defaults? can you try set spark.driver.maxResultSize to zero?

Comment: I updated the information in the question, and I try to set spark.driver.maxResultSize to zero, it doesn't work. @ShemTov